# Installing an older version of Chromium on Raspian Bullseye?

Tags: chromium, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have two Raspberry Pi Zero Ws with [Pimoroni HyperPixel 4 displays](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/hyperpixel-4) attached that run little dashboards in our lounge room by way of Chromium. One of the Pis had a hiccup and stopped booting so I wiped the card and figured I'd start afresh with Raspbian Bullseye since it was on Buster previously.

I've got nearly everything working again, but unfortunately the version of Chromium that comes with Bullseye as of writing (106) just plain refuses to run, when I attempt to launch it I get a dialog saying "Chromium is not supported on Raspberry Pi Zero W" and that's it.

Raspbian Buster has Chromium 90 and that launches fine (albeit extraordinarily slowly), but the HyperPixel 4 display under Buster requires a bunch of additional installation for the drivers as opposed to under Bullseye where they're built-in and it's a very minor effort to enable them and get the screen rotated around the correct way. As such, I'd *prefer* to stay with Bullseye and install an older Chromium but I haven't been able to figure out if that's actually possible?

(I'm not remotely concerned about security issues stemming from an old web browser because they're doing nothing but displaying a locally-hosted webpage. And I'd rather stick with Chromium if possible because I've already got the setup figured out for getting it to launch at boot into full screen and show my dashboard page.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps to install old version of Chromium browser. There is a downgrade-chromium option.

I just tried to install version 78 to replace the version 113 and it works fine for me on pi zero w with bullseye.